# Django query for getting common Libraries between book list

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 2 models linked with each other with Foreign key. A Book and a Library models.

I have a list of books IDs.
And I want to get the list of Libraries where I can find all those books

I’m trying not loop through all the libraries as there the number of both libraries and books list isn’t small

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code looks like this, based on your description above that uses just a ForeignKey:

```
class Library(models.Model):
    ...

class Book(models.Model):
    title = ...
    author = ...
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, related_name='books', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ....
```

Each Book has a ForeignKey pointing to its Library, but using a `related_name` defined for that `ForeignKey` you can have a reverse relation between the models.

In this example you can access all the books of a library with that related name by writing a simple query like `library.books.all()`.

To come to a conclusion, you can get all the libraries from a list of book ids using the `related_name` property in a query like this:

```
Library.objects.filter(books__id__in=book_ids).distinct()
```

Query above will filter all Library objects through `books` related name and return only those `Library` objects that have a `Book` whose id is found in the list of IDs called `book_ids`. Using `.distinct()` is just a nice practice to get a unique queryset.

**Additional suggestion**: In a setup like this where you have a `ForeignKey` only - one book cannot be found in more than one library. This is fine if each book is unique by some parameter. Though if you have a general book that can be found in multiple libraries I suggest you use a `ManyToMany` field.

**EDIT**:

We want to find the library that contains all the book ids from the list. How about trying something like this:

```
book_ids = [...]
Library.objects.annotate(
    books_count=Count('books', filter=Q(books__id__in=book_ids))
).filter(books_count__gte=books.count())
```

We count number of books for each Library but only if they satisfy a filter `books__id__in=book_ids` meaning that the book ID is in the list of ids. If the total count of filtered library books is the same as the list of ids than we've found our library.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This approach will list a Library if one of the book in a book list exist on it. what I want is list a library only if all the books on book list exist on it.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad, I added the edit at the bottom of the answer that should help.